# Is there anyway of programmatically scaling the number Heroku workers?

Tags: ruby, heroku

We need a method of determining the load and then scaling the number of dyno workers accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [workless gem](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) with DelayedJob and it works like a charm!

Basically you just need to install it and scale worker dynos to 0. When there's a new job added to DJ queue it picks it up in a few seconds, adds a worker and scales down when the task is performed. There are options for multiple workers but I never got so much jobs, so can't share any experience.

Comment: similarly I use https://github.com/JustinLove/autoscaler for SideKiq - also works like a charm.